# Xamarin getting an error when using 'app:errorEnabled=“true”' to TextInputLayout

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to create a registration page for an app in visual studio but whenever I try to add app:errorEnabled="true" to any of the TextInputLayouts, I get an error for all my IDs in the do not contain a definition. The moment I remove it, the errors are gone.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/emailField"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textColorHint="@color/white"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="23dp"
                app:errorEnabled="true"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp">

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/emailTxt"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

[Here's an image of the errors I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRvnv.png)

Comment: Please close your VS, then open your project folder, delete the `bin` and `obj` folders, then re-open your project in VS, rebuild it, if these errors will disappear.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't fix it

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT I put the errorEnabled part in an if statement in my c# code and it's working and not giving any errors anymore.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your sharing, please post you solution to answer, it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting errorEnabled to true in the C# file instead of the XML fixed the problem.

```
            string fullName, phoneNum, email, password;
            fullName = fullNameText.EditText.Text;
            phoneNum = phoneText.EditText.Text;
            email = emailtext.EditText.Text;
            password = passwordText.EditText.Text;

            if(fullName.Length <= 3)
            {
                fullNameText.ErrorEnabled = true;
                fullNameText.Error = "Please enter a valid name";
                return;
            }
            else if (!email.Contains("@"))
            {
                emailtext.ErrorEnabled = true;
                emailtext.Error = "Please enter a valid email";
                return;
            }
            else if(phoneNum.Length < 9)
            {
                phoneText.ErrorEnabled = true;
                phoneText.Error = "Please enter a valid phone number";
                return;
            }
            else if (password.Length < 8)
            {
                passwordText.ErrorEnabled = true;
                passwordText.Error = "Password should be at least 8 characters long";
                return;
            }
```